# Removing body class onClose with simplemodal

Tags: jquery, simplemodal, removeclass

I'm using Eric Martin's [SimpleModal plugin](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) for a page that has several different modals. One of the modal's has a different height and width than the others on the page, so I've added a class to the body when the link for the bigger modal is clicked. This works fine as far as controlling the style of that particular modal. But, removing the class when that modal is closed is an issue. I originally tried to use the onClose function, but I didn't have any success. So I tried to attach removeClass when you click the close link, but it's not removing the body class? Help?

Basically I want to do something like this to ensure that the class is removed when the modal is closed through any of the built in methods using the onClose function:

```
$("#element-id").modal({onClose: function () {
    $('body').removeClass('classname');
}});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of adding a class to the body, how about specifying the width/height of the modal for that particular modal?

Comment: I did try that, but it wouldn't allow me to add a class to the simple modal container, then I realized it had to do with my ordering (I was trying to addClass before the modal() was called (duh). So that works and I can achieve what I want with the sizing of the modals. But, I'm still interested in the future if it is possible to do what I'm asking above in the case I may need to use that method. :) Also, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#sample').modal({
    onOpen: function(dialog) {
        $('body').addClass('classname');
        dialog.overlay.show();
        dialog.container.show();
        dialog.data.show();
    },
    onClose: function(dialog) {
        $('body').removeClass('classname');
        $.modal.close()
    }
});​
```

If you want some smooth animation, you'll have to change `.show()` to something else.
Docs [here](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/).

Comment: It worked great! Thanks! I'd upvote you but I don't have enough rep points yet! :)